# Can one iPhone be registered to multiple Developer accounts?

Tags: ios, development, developer-program, uuid

I have an Apple iOS Developer account and I registered my iPhones UUID to this account (to create Provisioning Profiles, etc.).

Is it possible to add this iPhones UUID to another iOS Developer account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

A single device can be added to as many developer accounts as necessary.